# Removing myself from mirror

Tags: video, after-effects, camera, filming, mask

I'm going to shoot a real estate type of video of a local fashion/beauty salon (well, not a typical real estate video, I just need to showcase the studio which only has 2-3 rooms, that's it). The problem is, I have just inspected the place and to my surprise, it is full of mirrors, both the [ground floor](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15GCDpIxGX2HhGe3j_QVdCaqLcjE6g-fH?usp=drive_link) and the [first floor](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13jMQ18_zWKe1J4RchNJsX0MoqbZpXQZU?usp=drive_link). This latter one is especially tricky, because, as you can see, a little pathway leads up to the room. Now generally, the way I would shoot a real estate video, is that in case of each room I would want to walk through the doorstep (as a foreground) to give a feeling of actually entering that room, as if I was touring the house myself (as in [here](https://vimeo.com/130903115), for example). In my case however, it seems to be impossible without me showing up in the big mirror(s) in front. It's not like I can squat and problem solved, because I'll show up no matter what.

Question: how would you approach this problem professionally?

- Should I just try to shoot everything from the mirrors' direction, from the mirrors' point of view and thus potentially skipping any "walk through the doorway" kind of shots?
- Or, should I still force these walk through the doorway shots and then somehow try to remove myself from the image in post production (using After Effects I believe)? Or this latter would overcomplicate the issue a ton?

I tried to research the problem and I have only found to relevant posts. [This first one](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/filming-in-a-house-of-mirrors) mainly focuses on big budget Hollywood solutions (which is obviously not the situation in my case), this [second one](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24705/how-can-i-remove-an-object-from-a-shot) suggests that the problem could be tackled in After Effects by applying so called *clean plates*?

Any ideas or insights are highly appreciated.